# POST XML on Android by using HTTP

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient, http-post

I am trying to post xml on android. Same xml and server works on iphone perfectly, but on android i am getting invalid xml error message.

```
public void postData() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://stage.isadiasjd.com.tr/asdasdad-web/getProductDeviceService.do");

    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("<customer><districtId>2541</districtId><barcode>45464654654917</barcode><udid>dade51ce2c127310d1df5ee25e876e46feae470b</udid><email>Xzcxzcxzczxc@zxczxcxczxc.com</email><hashCode>2500a7005c01903093fa268984zczczczaeawdwa2w1d3w6dec9b61afbe28f37baad819ba3e0d</hashCode></customer>", "UTF-8");
       // se.setContentType("text/xml");
        se.setContentType("application/atom+xml");
        httppost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();

        String ss = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        Log.v("http req", ss);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("ex","1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("ex","2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you copy/paste the complete error message you receive (including the stack trace if any)? Thx!

Comment: <result>
 <errorCode>100</errorCode>
   <errorMsg>
   <message>invalid xml</message>
   </errorMsg>
 </result>

Comment: I am wondering whether your XML was url-encoded, in which case < and > would have been transformed in &lt; and &gt;, making the XML content invalid. Would you have a loog to the members of httppost with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Try application/json. On Android 2 something wrong with xml responses on some models